# Add Full screen mode for Embla Slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, carousel, embla-carousel

I'm using Embla Carousel, TailwindCSS and ShaDCN for React Typescript.
I have implemented a default carousel [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/embla-carousel-generator-react-q3v89d).

Now I want to implement a full-screen carousel modal when any item is clicked, please let me know how I can do that.

I have tried this [example](https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/html-image-zoom-on-click) but it only shows a single image.

Comment: Try using the same carousel instance, but displaying it as full-screen. Wrap the carousel in a `div` and conditionally apply Tailwind's `absolute z-50 left-0 top-0` classes to it. Use Embla's `pointerUp` event in order to toggle a `isFullscreen` reactive variable in React that then applies the classes to the `div`.